# WordPress - str_replace() not working with the_category(', ')

Tags: php, wordpress, string, replace

In WordPress, this works fine to retrieve my article category

```
the_category(', ');
```

It returns

```
<a href="/ghost-stories/" rel="category tag">Ghost Stories</a>
```

But its not working with str_replace

```
echo str_replace("ghost-stories", "blog", the_category(', '));
```

I want it to return

```
<a href="/blog/" rel="category tag">Ghost Stories</a>
```

It's not making any change

Comment: Wordpress functions prefixed with `the_` normally **output** the value and dont **return** them. Use [`get_the_category()'](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_category/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

As Code Spirit said `the_category` method prints the result to the screen.

But using [get_the_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) is not an immediate replacement of what it does.

You will need to look what it does return and handle the response accordingly (you might want to use `get_the_category_list()` if you want to handle the multiple-categories scenario).

Another *simpler* alternative would be to capture the output and then do the replacement before printing to screen.

```php
ob_start(); // Start capturing output.

the_category(' , '); // Will output the categories separated by commas.

$output = ob_get_clean(); // Stores the captured output into `$output`.

echo str_replace("ghost-stories", "blog", $output); // Replaces and prints.
```

Comment: The ob_start worked perfect thank you